# How to make main method calculate return value?

Tags: java

I wanted the user to enter the pay rate and hours worked. If the hours are 40 or below, it is to multiply the pay rate and the hours together. All of that is to happen in one method and the main method is supposed to call this. However, my program does nothing with the values.

```
package homework6;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Homework6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your pay rate.");
        double r = console.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("How many hours did you work this week?");
        int h = console.nextInt();

        double T1 = getTotalPay(r, h);
    }

    public static double getTotalPay(double r, int h){
        /*If the number of hours is less than or equal to 40, it simply
          multiplies them together and returns the result.*/
        if (h <= 40) {
            return r*h;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the method supposed to do if `h > 40`?

Comment: @Reimeus: If the number of hours is greater than
40, he gets an additional dollar for each hour over 40 that he or she has worked. I was going to program that part next, but first wanted to make sure I could get the first part working. This is the second assignment where I still cannot get the return statement to actually do something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you simply need to print the returned value:

```
...
double T1 = getTotalPay(r, h);
System.out.println("Total pay: " + T1);
```

As a matter of style, Java variables should start with a lower letter. You should change the name `T1` to `t1` (or, better, to something like `totalPay` that is more comprehensible).

Just to clarify: the above goes inside your `main()` method.

If you want to be fancy, you can format the result as currency:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your pay rate.");
    double r = console.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many hours did you work this week?");
    int h = console.nextInt();

    double totalPay = getTotalPay(r, h);
    System.out.println("Total pay: " + 
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(totalPay)
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the directions state that the main method is supposed to handle all print statements. this is why i cannot figure it out. i keep searching google, but i cannot get the return statement to calculate anything.

Comment: @tim71new - The code I suggested goes in `main`, so it will, in fact, conform to the directions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to print this returned value:

```
System.out.println(T1);
```

Second of all, your *getTotalPay(double r, int h)* method must **always** return something or throw an exception if the return type declared is not **void**. Right now it only returns something when the condition is satisfied. Did you even get this to compile? This method should look something like this:

```
public static double getTotalPay(double r, int h){

    if (h <= 40){
        return r*h;
    } else {
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my code worked, but did nothing besides display the user input. I copied and pasted your part over mine, and I got the same result.

Comment: You must add the System.out.println(T1) at the end of main method :)